# Sign In With Oauth In Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

My android app provide option to login with google account. For that i followed link https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/oauth-practices/mobile-apps-for-complex-login-systems/samplecode provided by google.

i cant understand some of the things in that code. so please help me in the following queries.

What is the url we need to load to open Google Login page in mobile with webview?

how to provide redirection url to our app?

What is YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_ENDPOINT?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I Changed the way, I used Google+ API ,because its simpler and newer way.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started